# How to convert string in UTF-8 to ASCII ignoring errors and removing non ASCII characters

Tags: scala, character-encoding

I am new to Scala.

Please advise how to convert strings in UTF-8 to ASCII ignoring errors and removing non ASCII characters in output.

For example, how to remove non ASCII character \uc382 from result string: "hello���", so that "hello" is printed in output.

```
scala.io.Source.fromBytes("hello\uc382".getBytes ("UTF-8"), "US-ASCII").mkString
```

Comment: Strings are UTF-16. If you had text in UTF-8 as bytes that is now in a String then it was converted. If you have text in a String and you want it in ASCII as bytes, you can converter it later. It seems that you just want to filter for only the UTF-16 code units for the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoints.

Comment: "hello\uc382" is a String. Therefore, it is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. If you want to filter them use @sjrd's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51566388/2226988). Your new code takes text as UTF-16 bytes and processes them as if they were US-ASCII bytes; that's not a success path. (Same applies to the code in your question.)

Comment: Thank you, What should be the proper way for programatic encoding conversion of a string   using an explicit target encoding definition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had text in UTF-8 as bytes that is now in a String then it was converted.

If you have text in a String and you want it in ASCII as bytes, you can convert it later.

It seems that you just want to filter for only the UTF-16 code units for the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoints. Fortunately, such codepoints take only one code unit so we can filter them directly without converting them to codepoints.

```
"hello\uC382"
  .filter(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(_) == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN)
  .getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
  .foreach { 
    println }
```

---

With the question generalized to an arbitrary, known character encoding, filtering doesn't do the job. Instead, the feature of the encoder to ignore characters that are not present in the target `Charset` can be used. An Encoder requires a bit more wrapping and unwrapping. (The API design is based on streaming and reusing the buffer within the same stream and even other streams.) So, with ISO_8859_1 as an example:

```
val encoder = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
  .newEncoder() 
  .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)
  .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)

val string = "ñhello\uc382"
println(string)
val chars = CharBuffer.allocate(string.length())
  .put(string)
chars.rewind()
val buffer = encoder.encode(chars)
val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](buffer.remaining())
buffer.get(bytes)
println(bytes)
bytes
  .foreach { 
    println }
```

Comment: This works, thank you. However the solution is using the fact that  ASCII is a subset of unicode as a result possible just to filer it's codepoints. Could you recommend a general solution for transforming to any target encoding, not limited to ASCII ?

Comment: The typical behavior for characters that the target character set does not support is to replace with, say, '?'. I generally prefer an exception, myself. Another option is to silently drop unsupported characters. Dropping is what you want?

Comment: Yes Tom, dropping is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
val str = "hello\uc382"
str.filter(_ <= 0x7f) // keep only valid ASCII characters
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. What should be the proper way for programatic encoding conversion  using an explicit source and target encoding definition ? Can scala.io.Source.fromBytes method be used in order to do the conversion ? Possibly engaging the following Codec definitions ?       
    implicit val codec = Codec("US-ASCII")
    codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)
    codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)